Compress DB (backup) in host machine from the script inside a docker container
In a Ubuntu server have a script that backups a postgres db with the following command:
pg_dump -U postgres -w -h 127.0.0.1 -F t $NOME_DA_BD > $BACKUP_PATH$BACKUP_NAME

This works well but now trying to run the script inside a docker container my Dockerfile is as follow:
FROM ubuntu:20.04
FROM postgres:17.0

COPY backup.sh /usr/local/bin/
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x backup.sh

#debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash && apt-get -y install cron
#RUN sudo apt install postgresql

CMD [“/bin/bash”] 
#RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls /usr/local/bin/'

the commands to build and run the container are as follow:
$ sudo docker build --no-cache -t hcorte/bakcup_container .

$ sudo docker run -v /mnt/backups/:/mnt/backups/ --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway -it hcorte/bakcup_container bash

root@79fc9d37136b:/usr/local/bin# sh backup.sh 10

the script have addapted for the container
pg_dump -U postgres -w -h host.docker.internal -F t $NOME_DA_BD > $BACKUP_PATH$BACKUP_NAME

changed to use host.docker.internal instead of 127.0.0.1 so it would compress the db that is in the host machine and not in a container what step am i missing?
but returns the error:

pg_dump: error: connection to server at "host.docker.internal"
(172.17.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused    Is the server
running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

extra steps from this post and post made those changes now returns:
pg_dump: error: connection to server at "host.docker.internal" (172.17.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.17.0.2", user "postgres", database "dvdrental", SSL encryption
connection to server at "host.docker.internal" (172.17.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.17.0.2", user "postgres", database "dvdrental", no encryption
(Solved) Got it to work with
editing /etc/postgresql/17/main/pg_hba.conf
and adding the following line for testing (gona change for a more secure way without opening all)
hostnossl all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
So in this case needed to make changes in postgres configurations make it work with docker.

postgres is listenning in that port 5432 and ip/host is localhost or 127.0.0.1 but since using docker and whant to point to the host from what get from other posts is that should use host.docker.internal to point to the host machine

postgres=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" on host "localhost" (address "127.0.0.1") at port "5432".
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off, ALPN: postgresql)

hum notice now someone is voting for closing the question, but at least give a reason or what additional information is needed...
